# How to manipulate the background color of a scene in three.js with shaders?

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js, shader, fragment-shader

I'd like to change the background color of a simple three.js scene, like the one you change with

```
renderer.setClearColor(/*insert color here*/)
```

or

```
scene.background = new THREE.Color(/*insert color here*/)
```

with fragment shaders,
but including glsl code or ShaderMaterial inside the brackets doesnt work.
How can I do it?

Comment: Use RenderTarget and its .texture propety in scene.background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach with `WebGLRenderTarget.texture` as `scene.background`:

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", event => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
  gu.resolution.set(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

let gu = {
  time: {value: 0},
  resolution: {value: new THREE.Vector2(innerWidth, innerHeight)}
}

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2));

let ico = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(3, 0), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff4488}));
scene.add(ico);

// <background stuff>
let backScene = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x004488,
  onBeforeCompile: shader =>  {
  shader.uniforms.time = gu.time;
  shader.uniforms.resolution = gu.resolution;
  shader.vertexShader = `
    varying vec2 vUv;
  ` + shader.vertexShader;
  shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
    `#include <uv_vertex>`,
    `vUv = uv;`
  );
  shader.fragmentShader = `
    ${noise}
    uniform float time;
    uniform vec2 resolution;
    varying vec2 vUv;
  ` + shader.fragmentShader;
  shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
    `vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );`,
    `
      vec2 tUv = vUv * 5.0;
      tUv.x *= resolution.x / resolution.y;
      float t = time * 0.5;
      tUv -= vec2(t * 0.25, t);
      float n1 = snoise(vec3(tUv, time * 0.125));
      n1 = (n1 + 1.0) * 0.5;
      
      float n2 = snoise(vec3(n1 * 10., 1, 1));
      n2 = sin(((n2 + 1.0) * 0.5) * 3.1415926 * 2.);
      
      float effect = smoothstep(0.1, 0.125, n1) * (1. - smoothstep(0.375, 0.4, n2));
      float coef = sin(n2 * 3.141526 * 0.5) * 0.125;
      float e = effect - abs(coef);
      e = n1 > 0.25 && n1 < 0.75? e * e : pow(e, 16.);

      vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(diffuse * e, opacity);
    `
  );
}
}));
let backCamera = new THREE.Camera();
let backRT = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(innerWidth, innerHeight);
scene.background = backRT.texture; // assign to background
// </background stuff>

let clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop( _ => {
  let t = clock.getElapsedTime();
  gu.time.value = t;
  
  ico.rotation.x = t * 0.31;
  ico.rotation.y = t * 0.27;
  
  renderer.setRenderTarget(backRT); // set render target
  renderer.render(backScene, backCamera); //render background
  
  renderer.setRenderTarget(null); // remove render target, render to default buffer
  renderer.render(scene, camera); // render scene
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
  var noise = `
  //
// Description : Array and textureless GLSL 2D/3D/4D simplex 
//               noise functions.
//      Author : Ian McEwan, Ashima Arts.
//  Maintainer : stegu
//     Lastmod : 20110822 (ijm)
//     License : Copyright (C) 2011 Ashima Arts. All rights reserved.
//               Distributed under the MIT License. See LICENSE file.
//               https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise
//               https://github.com/stegu/webgl-noise
// 

vec3 mod289(vec3 x) {
  return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
}

vec4 mod289(vec4 x) {
  return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;
}

vec4 permute(vec4 x) {
     return mod289(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x);
}

vec4 taylorInvSqrt(vec4 r)
{
  return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r;
}

float snoise(vec3 v)
  { 
  const vec2  C = vec2(1.0/6.0, 1.0/3.0) ;
  const vec4  D = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0);

// First corner
  vec3 i  = floor(v + dot(v, C.yyy) );
  vec3 x0 =   v - i + dot(i, C.xxx) ;

// Other corners
  vec3 g = step(x0.yzx, x0.xyz);
  vec3 l = 1.0 - g;
  vec3 i1 = min( g.xyz, l.zxy );
  vec3 i2 = max( g.xyz, l.zxy );

  //   x0 = x0 - 0.0 + 0.0 * C.xxx;
  //   x1 = x0 - i1  + 1.0 * C.xxx;
  //   x2 = x0 - i2  + 2.0 * C.xxx;
  //   x3 = x0 - 1.0 + 3.0 * C.xxx;
  vec3 x1 = x0 - i1 + C.xxx;
  vec3 x2 = x0 - i2 + C.yyy; // 2.0*C.x = 1/3 = C.y
  vec3 x3 = x0 - D.yyy;      // -1.0+3.0*C.x = -0.5 = -D.y

// Permutations
  i = mod289(i); 
  vec4 p = permute( permute( permute( 
             i.z + vec4(0.0, i1.z, i2.z, 1.0 ))
           + i.y + vec4(0.0, i1.y, i2.y, 1.0 )) 
           + i.x + vec4(0.0, i1.x, i2.x, 1.0 ));

// Gradients: 7x7 points over a square, mapped onto an octahedron.
// The ring size 17*17 = 289 is close to a multiple of 49 (49*6 = 294)
  float n_ = 0.142857142857; // 1.0/7.0
  vec3  ns = n_ * D.wyz - D.xzx;

  vec4 j = p - 49.0 * floor(p * ns.z * ns.z);  //  mod(p,7*7)

  vec4 x_ = floor(j * ns.z);
  vec4 y_ = floor(j - 7.0 * x_ );    // mod(j,N)

  vec4 x = x_ *ns.x + ns.yyyy;
  vec4 y = y_ *ns.x + ns.yyyy;
  vec4 h = 1.0 - abs(x) - abs(y);

  vec4 b0 = vec4( x.xy, y.xy );
  vec4 b1 = vec4( x.zw, y.zw );

  //vec4 s0 = vec4(lessThan(b0,0.0))*2.0 - 1.0;
  //vec4 s1 = vec4(lessThan(b1,0.0))*2.0 - 1.0;
  vec4 s0 = floor(b0)*2.0 + 1.0;
  vec4 s1 = floor(b1)*2.0 + 1.0;
  vec4 sh = -step(h, vec4(0.0));

  vec4 a0 = b0.xzyw + s0.xzyw*sh.xxyy ;
  vec4 a1 = b1.xzyw + s1.xzyw*sh.zzww ;

  vec3 p0 = vec3(a0.xy,h.x);
  vec3 p1 = vec3(a0.zw,h.y);
  vec3 p2 = vec3(a1.xy,h.z);
  vec3 p3 = vec3(a1.zw,h.w);

//Normalise gradients
  vec4 norm = taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(p0,p0), dot(p1,p1), dot(p2, p2), dot(p3,p3)));
  p0 *= norm.x;
  p1 *= norm.y;
  p2 *= norm.z;
  p3 *= norm.w;

// Mix final noise value
  vec4 m = max(0.6 - vec4(dot(x0,x0), dot(x1,x1), dot(x2,x2), dot(x3,x3)), 0.0);
  m = m * m;
  return 42.0 * dot( m*m, vec4( dot(p0,x0), dot(p1,x1), 
                                dot(p2,x2), dot(p3,x3) ) );
}
`;
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, I wish I could have a simpler example though, I'm a beginner so there's too much going on here. I'll keep studying though so I'll certainly come back here later.